# Normal Distribution website

Tags: normal-distribution

I dont know if this is allowed to be asked but I'm trying to teach myself probability and statistics. I've moved onto Normal distriibuton and cumulative distribution functions and I can't find any great websites that have basic ways of describing how formulas work. I'm just wondering if there are any great websites you know of I could teach myself with? Thanks

Comment: I think that you must start from books instead of a website. The reason is that in general a website is not very well structured to understand deeply the concepts, by example, you need to do exercises to understand any topic correctly. There are a lot of books in PDF format in the web from where you can start to learn. You can see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbook-recommendation%5D+introduction+probability+statistics) for some guidance.

Comment: [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics-probability/modeling-distributions-of-data#normal-distributions-library)has a section on normal distributions.

Comment: Wikipedia. $ $ $ $

Answer (score 0):

Khan Academy has already been mentioned but i have to add this: there you usually won't find great explanations of how formulas work. I'm a Statistics major and i have used Khan Academy and, when it concerns explanations of how formulas work, you will find only a good video or 2 about the Poisson process.

Undergrad level books and Khan Academy aren't strong on proofs for the formulas that you are looking for, because those proofs require fancier math than the necessary to use them. I think you will find what you are looking for only in sophisticated books.

Answer (score -1):

See this one:

http://stattrek.com/tutorials/statistics-tutorial.aspx

http://stattrek.com/probability-distributions/normal.aspx?Tutorial=Stat

Here is another:

http://www.intmath.com/counting-probability/11-probability-distributions-concepts.php

And if you google

https://www.google.com.br/?gws_rd=ssl#q=probability+distribution+examples+pdf&*&spf=109

you will find a lot of information.